# Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

I'm attempting to install PuppetDB but I'm running into an issue when executing `puppet -t`. I'm getting:

```
Error: Cached facts for puppet.asc.ohio-state.edu failed: Could not find terminus
puppetdb for indirection facts
```

I've installed the `puppet-terminus` package so I'm not certain what the issue is. Anyone know how to debug/solve this?

Comment: Your puppet master process is having problems connecting to PuppetDB.  Have you completed the steps in [this doc](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/latest/connect_puppet_master.html)?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Yes, I've followed that doc but to no avail.

Comment: Oddly it seems to work when running `puppet agent -t` on other nodes. The only issue is when it's run on the `puppet` node itself (where the master/puppetdb are also located). Any ideas @ShaneMadden'

Comment: Oh - what's your puppet.conf look like on that node?  Likely some bit of config in the `[main]` block that needs to be in `[master]` only.

Comment: I just had this issue on FreeBSD where they've just removed the Puppet 6 packages in favour of Puppet 7.   The deleted answer gave me the hint I needed - I had to also upgrade the `puppetdb-terminus` package.

Answer (score 0):

If the `puppet agent -t` works on other nodes but the puppet server itself, then make sure that `which puppet` points to the right puppet binary file, if you have 2 puppet agent versions installed for example, you are more likely to have this issue.